# Building a Backbone collection-view that saves the mode-views it renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, view

I have the following Backbone view:

```
var app = app || {};

app.QuestionListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    },

    render: function(e) {
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            var q = new app.QuestionItemView({model: model});
            q.render();
        });
    }
});
```

I'm trying to iterate over its collection and insert a list element for every model in the collection.  The way I'm implementing it right now, each time the collection-view renders, it has to recreate each model-view.  How would I implement it so that once the model-views have been created, they would just render without being reinitialized or refetching the models they are linked to?

My initial attempt was to create the models in the `initialize` function.  However, this does not work because the collection is not populated in time to give the model-views their models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for your collection's reset event in your collection view's initialize method, then call render in the initialize method for each QuestionItemView. The collection will be ready when reset fires.

in QuestionListView:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
}
```

in QuestionItemView:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.render();
}
```